# How to copy subfolders in docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have following folder structure:

```
nova-components
    component1
        dist
        ...
    component2
        dist
        ...
    component3
        dist
        ...
    ...
```

Is there any way to copy only dist folders in docker.
I am thinking about something like:

```
COPY --from=assets /nova-components/*/dist /var/www/nova-components/*/dist
```

The end goal is to include generated dist folders in the final image and keep the directory tree structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently `multi-stage docker build` do not respect `.dockerignore`, see this [discussion](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/33923), so you had to do it yourself, one way is to clean things in the first stage, like follows:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04 AS assets

RUN mkdir -p /nova-components/component1/dist && \
  mkdir -p /nova-components/component1/others && \
  mkdir -p /nova-components/component2/dist && \
  mkdir -p /nova-components/component2/others

RUN find /nova-components/*/* ! -name "dist" -maxdepth 0 | xargs rm -fr

FROM ubuntu:16.04

COPY --from=assets /nova-components /var/www/nova-components/

RUN ls -alh /var/www/nova-components
RUN ls -alh /var/www/nova-components/*
```

**test:**

```
# docker build --no-cache -t try:1 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/7 : FROM ubuntu:16.04 AS assets
 ---> b9e15a5d1e1a
Step 2/7 : RUN mkdir -p /nova-components/component1/dist &&   mkdir -p /nova-components/component1/others &&   mkdir -p /nova-components/component2/dist &&   mkdir -p /nova-components/component2/others
 ---> Running in d4c9c422d53a
Removing intermediate container d4c9c422d53a
 ---> d316032dd59d
Step 3/7 : RUN find /nova-components/*/* ! -name "dist" -maxdepth 0 | xargs rm -fr
 ---> Running in b6168b027f4c
Removing intermediate container b6168b027f4c
 ---> 9deb57cb5153
Step 4/7 : FROM ubuntu:16.04
 ---> b9e15a5d1e1a
Step 5/7 : COPY --from=assets /nova-components /var/www/nova-components/
 ---> 49301f701db2
Step 6/7 : RUN ls -alh /var/www/nova-components
 ---> Running in 9ed0cafff2fb
total 16K
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4.0K Nov  6 02:13 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Nov  6 02:13 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Nov  6 02:13 component1
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Nov  6 02:13 component2
Removing intermediate container 9ed0cafff2fb
 ---> f1ee82cff972
Step 7/7 : RUN ls -alh /var/www/nova-components/*
 ---> Running in 23a27e5ce853
/var/www/nova-components/component1:
total 12K
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Nov  6 02:13 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4.0K Nov  6 02:13 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Nov  6 02:13 dist

/var/www/nova-components/component2:
total 12K
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Nov  6 02:13 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4.0K Nov  6 02:13 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Nov  6 02:13 dist
Removing intermediate container 23a27e5ce853
 ---> b9d5ab8f5157
Successfully built b9d5ab8f5157
Successfully tagged try:1
```

With the clean in first stage using `RUN find /nova-components/*/* ! -name "dist" -maxdepth 0 | xargs rm -fr`, then you can make it, let's wait for possible official feature support.

Comment: It looks more like a hack than proper solution, but in docker I have a feeling that everything looks like a hack. 
At least it works and its better than 20 lines of `COPY --from=assets`. 
Also your command was deleting also contents of dist folders so I had to tweak it to get a good solution. 
`RUN find /nova-components/*/* ! -name "dist" -maxdepth 0  | xargs rm -fr`

Answer (score 0):

Add a `.dockerignore` file with your `Dockerfile`

```
nova-components/*/*
!nova-components/*/dist
```

And copy like

```
COPY nova-components/ /var/www/nova-components
```

EDIT

So with multi stage build, this is currently not working. A new solution is to run, on the last stage,

```
rsync -avz --include='dist/' nova-components/ nova-components-dist/.
```

then at the final stage,

```
COPY --from=assets /nova-components-dist/ /var/www/nova-components
```